# How do I change my "Recommended Applications" list (shown after right click > open with) for a given file extension?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, defaults

OSX v. 10.9.3

When I "right click" a *.kml file and go to "Open With", the list of applications does not include QGis, my favorite program for medium to heavy duty GIS work.

I'd like QGis to be on that list. I strongly suspect some light to moderate coding will be  involved, but it would save me from another tiny frustration in my workflow..

Thanks

Comment: I wonder if using Get Info's (Command + I) on a document and then using the "Open with" section to change all would add it to the list. You can then change it back to whatever default you'd like those files to have, unless you do want to keep it as QGI.

Comment: It can. But its not ideal in most cases. I don't want qgis to be the default application to open Google Earth's KML files.

Comment: Understood. I was wondering if adding and then changing the default application back to whatever you prefer would still leave QGis in the list of recommended apps. Easy enough to try it out.

Comment: Tried it, no that would be sensible on Apple's part but that's not how it was programmed

Comment: OK, my next best guess is that it's part of the Info.plist under the 'Contents' folder when you right-click an application file and choose 'Show Package Contents'. A quick check shows that there's a 'Document types' section. May need to have Xcode installed to view the plist files.

Comment: You might also try asking this question here http://gis.stackexchange.com

Comment: The question doesn't pertain to GIS I think..